# How to hide a SharePoint tab on 100 sites? (SP2010)

Tags: navigation

I have 100 team sites in SharePoint 2010. At the last minute, I have been asked to hide a tab on each of these sites. Through the GUI, I could do this by using the Navigation option under Site Settings, but I would have to do it for all 100 sites. Is there a way to do this programmatically? Or globally through the GUI (I doubt this is an option)? I have tried using JQuery, but due to the lag, it is not a viable option. I figured there may also be the possibility to write a powershell script to do this - I am just still new to powershell.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do to avoid people from seeing your tab for split second before being hidden by jQuery, is rather than hide that tab on page load (which has a short delay) reference a custom css that hides all tabs by default and unhide all but your tab on page load using jQuery.

Comment: yeah, I have used this approach before. Definitely a good one. Problem is, that I have my jquery references in a web part that gets loaded onto the page, because I have some Bamboo Web Parts that use jquery, and the js conflicts. So, either way there is a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a

> style="display:none;"

on that tab? Keep in mind, that the content is than available in the html. So a search engine may find and index that content.